# URL link in a label which text comes from server

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, label

So there is a dynamic text coming from the server and it displays on UILabel. 
There is a link in the text and i want to let users click on the link so they will be directed to the website on this link. 
Is it possible to do that? 
And if so, how can i do that? 
Thanks everybody !

Comment: anything still unclear? @Student :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `UITextView`, you will get this behavior almost for free. Set the `textView.dataDetectors` property to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openURL:)];
[aLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And then implement the method that it calls:

```
- (void)openURL:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)tap.view;
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:label.text];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:targetURL];
}
```

**Note:** this will only work if the label **only** hast the URL as its `text`. if there is something like `the link is: http://www.example.org` instead of only `http://www.example.org` then you'll have to adjust your code appropriately